# Camel servlet to listen address

Tags: java, spring, servlets, apache-camel

I have a program that listens to ftp address and whenever new file appears it takes it and converts to pojo. But I run it from `main()` method. It's not very comfortable.

I would like to create a servlet that will do the same, but i will create `war` file and put it into TomCat and the program will run itself, so i wouldn't have to run it.

I have created `web.xml` with camel servlet and spring listener and don't know what my further steps should be.

Here's what I have now:

My class:

```
@Component
public class test extends SpringRouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("ftp://Mike@localhost?noop=true&binary=true").to("file://data");
            }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:camel-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

camel-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.apache.camel.spring.issues.contextscan"/>

<camelContext id="camel5" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="myBuilder" />
</camelContext>

<bean id="myBuilder" class="test"/>
```

**UPD:**

Now i see that my program connects to ftp, but it doesn't copy files.

I pasted log i'm getting http://pastebin.com/2tTf6QmL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I make from the question is that you are trying to use camel-servlet component for initializing camel routes in a web-application. Camel-servlet component is not meant for doing this. If you are using spring with camel, then configure Spring web context loader `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and import the spring-camel xml's in spring application context file.

Comment: Please, check my post update. I would like to know, how can I make my `Converter` class to execute automatically, after i start server.

Comment: Ok, you do not need to have the camel servlet in your web application. 1)Remove the servlet and servlet-mapping tags from web.xml.2)Write your route by extending the SpringRouteBuilder and configure your route. 3). Use spring's support for camel to scan your route class. Check the following page for complete details. Specifically the section :Using contextScan

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Now i can't figure out why files aren't being copied. Could you please help?

Comment: Set the [tracer](http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html) attribute on CamelContext to true and debug your route.

Comment: Did it. Seems i'm getting OK without any error. Pasted log into original post.

Comment: Check for directory named "data" in the directory from where you are starting tomcat

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was looking for this directory inside my projects' folder, not tomcat.